Reordering Treeview items via drag/drop
I have a two level deep collection that it's bound to (collection of parent items where each parent has a collection of child items). I'm trying to use the gong solutions package (https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop) to re-order the collections by simply dragging one to a new spot using the insertion adorner to preview where it would drop.
At the parent level it works fine, but at the child level, as you drag it over each item it shoots to the top of its parent collection and then back down. It's like there's a separate container for each item that it thinks is the parent item? The gif below shows the issue I'm seeing.

Very basic models/collections:
public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ObservableCollection<Child> { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Child>();
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

And in my viewmodel:
public string ObservableCollection<Parent> { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Parent>(); // treeview's itemsource bound to this

In the DragOver function I'm simply checking the dropInfo's Data's type, and if it is type Child and the targetItem is type child, then checking if they have the same parent before setting the insertion adorner.
public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    // Determine whether the dragged item can be dropped at the target location
    if (dropInfo.Data is Child draggedChild && dropInfo.TargetItem is Child targetChild)
    {
        // Allow drop only within the same parent
        var sourceParent = GetParent(draggedChild);
        var targetParent = GetParent(targetChild);

        if (sourceParent == targetParent)
        {
            dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
            dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Insert;
        }
        else
        {
            dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }
    else if (dropInfo.Data is Child && dropInfo.TargetItem is Parent)
    {
        // Prevent Child being dropped directly onto an Parent
        dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
    else if (dropInfo.Data is Parent && dropInfo.TargetItem is Parent)
    {
        // Allow Parent to be reordered with another Parent
        dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Insert;
    }
    else
    {
        dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}

